# Postgres DB getting overloaded when generating a sitemap in Django

Tags: django, postgresql

I am generating a sitemap for a Django model. However, the Postgres DB gets overloaded filtering the table we're indexing. This causes the site to experience downtime for hours, because the database is backed up.

The exact query causing the issue is:

`Books.objects.all().exclude(has_kindle__isnull=True).order_by('-has_kindle', '-id').select_related('publisher')`

The table has 3M rows, and the results are about 300k, divided into separate smaller sitemaps, each with 10k links each.

Is it normal for the query above to cause the database to totally seize up like that? Is there anything wrong with this query that could be optimized? Any and all ideas much appreciated!

Comment: What indexes do you have? If you are sorting 300k rows on a non-indexed `has_kindle` field with a small db that could certainly cause issues. I would also try `.prefetch_related('publisher')` assuming there are many fewer publishers than books so you are not joining the publisher table for each of the 300k rows.

Comment: Thanks @azundo. I didn't think about indexes, let me check. And also investigate using `prefetch`. There are indeed *far* less publishers than books.

Comment: Just checked and `has_kindle` does have an index.  Will try playing around with `prefetch_related` to see if we can gain any wins there.

Comment: you may want to look into clustering the index or indexes you have

Comment: I would find the actual SQL statements that cause the problems, probably from the PostgreSQL log, and start tuning these.